# Animation Library for C#

Tags: c#, animation

Hi All
I want to make some animation using c#.Animation should include water falling from sprinkler in garden.Please suggest any plausible solutions.

Comment: Ok I know that there are some great people out there who think that this question is stupidest question but this is like this as i donot have any knowledge how would this be implemented.Please tell why to down vote and close this question

Comment: downvotes are most likely because this type of question is generally considered "low quality."  It appears you're asking the equivalent of "I want a car how do I make car" a question that cannot truly be answered.  Creating an animation of water falling from a sprinkler is spectacularly difficult.  I understand that you actually want some kind of library that assists in creating such an animation (physics, water simulation, animation) but even that's a tall order.  Questions like this should be shelved until after you've started work and have more specific questions about the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to us Silverlight or WPF using expression blend. Since you haven't mentioned your delivery mechanism (app or web site) I will mention use Silverlight for a website and WPF for a desktop app.

Other options include:
GDI (the native windows graphics)
OpenGL / DirectX, etc (like games, etc)
Pre rendered video (Like TV)